# jQuery delegate with button loaded via JavaScript

Tags: jquery, delegates

I've searched through stackoverflow as well as the rest of the web without finding a clear answer for what I am trying to do.  I have the following HTML code:

```
<a id="orderPadReviewSubmitBtn" href="#" class="portlet-lightGrey-button  float-right"><span>Submit order</span></a>
```

which is loaded via JavaScript from a button click.  I am attempting to use delegate as the **jQuery on the site is 1.4.2**, so no "on()" is available.

The code I am trying is this:

```
$("a[id=orderPadReviewSubmitBtn]").delegate("span","load", function(){
$("#orderPadReviewSubmitBtn").mousedown(function(){alert("Order Submitted");}); });
```

I have also tried:

```
$("#orderPadReviewSubmitBtn").delegate("span","load", function(){
$("#orderPadReviewSubmitBtn").mousedown(function(){alert("Order Submitted");}); })
```

These work if loaded once the above button is loaded, but not if I run the jQuery before the button is loaded.

My ultimate goal is to be able to run some other function once this button loads and someone clicks on it.

I have a feeling that there is something simple I am missing, and your help in finding the issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything I have read said to stay away from .live() and use .delegate() for this.

Comment: Actually delegate was added in 1.4.2 so you should use that instead.  Also whats the reason for binding the load event?

Comment: Yeah, you should be binding the click event.

Comment: I wasn't able to get delegate to work, but was able to get the desired result using live (I know, I said myself that I shouldn't), but it worked.  The final code was $("#orderPadReviewSubmitBtn").live("click", function(){alert("Order Submitted");});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), it isn't depreciated in 1.4, your code would end up being this:

```
$("a[id=orderPadReviewSubmitBtn]").live("mousedown", function() {
    alert("Order Submitted");
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/d2SYE/

And, as you mentioned, if you wanted to call another function you'd use this:

```
$("a[id=orderPadReviewSubmitBtn]").live("mousedown", newFunc);

function newFunc() {
    alert("Order Submitted");
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/YwNyP/

Comment: Looks to me like a misunderstanding on his part - not being rude but he's obviously not that familiar with jQuery.  I get what you mean though.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that a moment ago myself.  Facepalm :)

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your help.  @Archer, you are correct.  I am a JS guy who is now trying to do everything I can in jQuery as it is much better in many ways.  Now I more clearly understand how delegate and live works.

Comment: @Andrew Stick with it mate - it's AWESOME when you start getting into it :D

Comment: @Archer +1 Definitely, but, there's one downside, you end up loving it so much you never use vanilla JS again and then when you have to you can barely stumble through it! (That's a slight exaggeration but it's close, if I try vanilla I find myself using JQ methods!)

Comment: @A.M.K. So very true...I actually get a little depressed when I have to use JS for something where I know jQuery would have been much easier/cleaner.  Fortunately, most of my clients have jQuery so I don't have to be sad very often.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the load event handler

```
// bind event handler to parent that exists at the time dom is ready
// it will then listen for click event from element with id=orderPadReviewSubmitBtn
$(function(){ // <-- put your code inside a document.ready function
    $('body').delegate('#orderPadReviewSubmitBtn','click',function(){
        alert("Order Submitted");
    });   
});
```

Replacing `body` with the closest static parent element

I think you don't understand how delegation works - That's why you think you need the `load` event.  How it works is you bind it to a parent element that already exists and is static(meaning it won't change) - It will then listen for the events you specify, as they bubble up from the specific element/elements you use chose(in this case your element with `id=orderPadReviewSubmitBtn`)

Comment: That's still a load event handler :)

Comment: @A.M.K What's a load event handler?

Comment: `$(function(){` is actually just a wrapper function for `window.onload`.

Comment: Actually - `$(function() == $(document).ready(function()` which is not the same as window.onload.  Read more about it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3698214/1385672

Comment: I stand corrected, partially. As you can see [here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.bindReady) it calls `DOMContentLoaded` and falls back to `onload`.